# Do newly added Couchbase servers need to be added to client configurations to be leveraged?

Tags: c#, couchbase

I'm working with Couchbase, specifically using the .NET client. We're unsure whether we need to add a load balancer for Couchbase. I know we don't need one to actually balance the nodes, but I'm unsure if we need one to allow for adding servers on the fly.

Consider the following .NET Couchbase configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="couchbase" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase"/>
  </configSections>
  <couchbase>
    <servers bucket="default" bucketPassword="">
      <add uri="http://192.168.0.2:8091/pools"/>
      <add uri="http://192.168.0.3:8091/pools"/>
    </servers>
  </couchbase>
</configuration>
```

Now say we add another server to the cluster, located at:

```
192.168.0.4:8091
```

If an application is already deployed with the configuration with two servers, will it be able to leverage the newly added server? Or do all client configurations need to have an element added like:

```
<add uri="http://192.168.0.4:8091/pools"/>
```

Our thought is that if all configurations would need to be updated that we could just point all clients to a load balancer instead, and add the new servers to the load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this architectural white paper (pdf) on Couchbase it says:

> To talk to Couchbase Server, applications use memcached compatible smart-client SDKs in a variety of languages
>   including Java, .NET, PHP, Python, Ruby, C, and C++. These clients are cluster topology aware and get updates on
>   the cluster map. They automatically send request from the application to the appropriate server.

http://info.couchbase.com/couchbase-server-architecture-review.html

It is also mentioned here in the documentation if you don't want to download the pdf.  http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#rebalancing

Comment: Thank you - I read through the .NET client documentation, but I didn't think to check the whitepaper (RTFM?). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

it's recommended by Couchbase to have all cluster nodes in the connection configuration of the application. Nevertheless, it is not really required - cluster map will be updated from servers that are in the application configuration.

Daniel